# TeXstudio: "... does not look like a valid PDF document. Either the file is corrupt or it is in the process of creation."

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, texstudio

I am new to Latex and Tikz and I am trying to view this periodic table (https://texample.net/tikz/examples/periodic-table-of-chemical-elements) in Texstudio. However, I get the error that I mentioned in the title.
Does anyone know why and can help me?
Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,calc}

\ifpdf
%
\else
% Implement Outline text using pstricks if regular LaTeX->dvi->ps->pdf route
\usepackage{pst-all}
\fi

\begin{document}
    
    \newcommand{\CommonElementTextFormat}[4]
    {
        \begin{minipage}{2.2cm}
            \centering
            {\textbf{#1} \hfill #2}%
            \linebreak \linebreak
            {\textbf{#3}}%
            \linebreak \linebreak
            {{#4}}
        \end{minipage}
    }
    
    \newcommand{\NaturalElementTextFormat}[4]
    {
        \CommonElementTextFormat{#1}{#2}{\LARGE {#3}}{#4}
    }
    
    \newcommand{\OutlineText}[1]
    {
        \ifpdf
        % Couldn't find a nicer way of doing an outline font with TikZ
        % other than using pdfliteral 1 Tr
        %
        \pdfliteral direct {0.5 w 1 Tr}{#1}%
        \pdfliteral direct {1 w 0 Tr}%
        \else
        % pstricks can do this with \pscharpath from pstricks
        %
        \pscharpath[shadow=false,
        fillstyle=solid,
        fillcolor=white,
        linestyle=solid,
        linecolor=black,
        linewidth=.2pt]{#1} 
        \fi
    }
    
    \newcommand{\SyntheticElementTextFormat}[4]
    {
        \ifpdf
        \CommonElementTextFormat{#1}{#2}{\OutlineText{\LARGE #3}}{#4}
        \else
        % pstricks approach results in slightly larger box
        % that doesn't break, so fudge here
        \CommonElementTextFormat{#1}{#2}{\OutlineText{\Large #3}}{#4}
        \fi
    }
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily, scale=0.45, transform shape]
        
        %% Fill Color Styles
        \tikzstyle{ElementFill} = [fill=yellow!15]
        \tikzstyle{AlkaliMetalFill} = [fill=blue!55]
        \tikzstyle{AlkalineEarthMetalFill} = [fill=blue!40]
        \tikzstyle{MetalFill} = [fill=blue!25]
        \tikzstyle{MetalloidFill} = [fill=orange!25]
        \tikzstyle{NonmetalFill} = [fill=green!25]
        \tikzstyle{HalogenFill} = [fill=green!40]
        \tikzstyle{NobleGasFill} = [fill=green!55]
        \tikzstyle{LanthanideActinideFill} = [fill=purple!25]
        
        %% Element Styles
        \tikzstyle{Element} = [draw=black, ElementFill,
        minimum width=2.75cm, minimum height=2.75cm, node distance=2.75cm]
        \tikzstyle{AlkaliMetal} = [Element, AlkaliMetalFill]
        \tikzstyle{AlkalineEarthMetal} = [Element, AlkalineEarthMetalFill]
        \tikzstyle{Metal} = [Element, MetalFill]
        \tikzstyle{Metalloid} = [Element, MetalloidFill]
        \tikzstyle{Nonmetal} = [Element, NonmetalFill]
        \tikzstyle{Halogen} = [Element, HalogenFill]
        \tikzstyle{NobleGas} = [Element, NobleGasFill]
        \tikzstyle{LanthanideActinide} = [Element, LanthanideActinideFill]
        \tikzstyle{PeriodLabel} = [font={\sffamily\LARGE}, node distance=2.0cm]
        \tikzstyle{GroupLabel} = [font={\sffamily\LARGE}, minimum width=2.75cm, node distance=2.0cm]
        \tikzstyle{TitleLabel} = [font={\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}]
        
        %% Group 1 - IA
        \node[name=H, Element] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{1}{1.0079}{H}{Hydrogen}};
        \node[name=Li, below of=H, AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{3}{6.941}{Li}{Lithium}};
        \node[name=Na, below of=Li, AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{11}{22.990}{Na}{Sodium}};
        \node[name=K, below of=Na, AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{19}{39.098}{K}{Potassium}};
        \node[name=Rb, below of=K, AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{37}{85.468}{Rb}{Rubidium}};
        \node[name=Cs, below of=Rb, AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{55}{132.91}{Cs}{Caesium}};
        \node[name=Fr, below of=Cs, AlkaliMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{87}{223}{Fr}{Francium}};
        
        %% Group 2 - IIA
        \node[name=Be, right of=Li, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{4}{9.0122}{Be}{Beryllium}};
        \node[name=Mg, below of=Be, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{12}{24.305}{Mg}{Magnesium}};
        \node[name=Ca, below of=Mg, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{20}{40.078}{Ca}{Calcium}};
        \node[name=Sr, below of=Ca, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{38}{87.62}{Sr}{Strontium}};
        \node[name=Ba, below of=Sr, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{56}{137.33}{Ba}{Barium}};
        \node[name=Ra, below of=Ba, AlkalineEarthMetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{88}{226}{Ra}{Radium}};
        
        %% Group 3 - IIIB
        \node[name=Sc, right of=Ca, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{21}{44.956}{Sc}{Scandium}};
        \node[name=Y, below of=Sc, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{39}{88.906}{Y}{Yttrium}};
        \node[name=LaLu, below of=Y, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{57-71}{}{La-Lu}{Lanthanide}};
        \node[name=AcLr, below of=LaLu, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{89-103}{}{Ac-Lr}{Actinide}};
        
        %% Group 4 - IVB
        \node[name=Ti, right of=Sc, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{22}{47.867}{Ti}{Titanium}};
        \node[name=Zr, below of=Ti, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{40}{91.224}{Zr}{Zirconium}};
        \node[name=Hf, below of=Zr, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{72}{178.49}{Hf}{Halfnium}};
        \node[name=Rf, below of=Hf, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{104}{261}{Rf}{Rutherfordium}};
        
        %% Group 5 - VB
        \node[name=V, right of=Ti, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{23}{50.942}{V}{Vanadium}};
        \node[name=Nb, below of=V, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{41}{92.906}{Nb}{Niobium}};
        \node[name=Ta, below of=Nb, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{73}{180.95}{Ta}{Tantalum}};
        \node[name=Db, below of=Ta, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{105}{262}{Db}{Dubnium}};
        
        %% Group 6 - VIB
        \node[name=Cr, right of=V, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{24}{51.996}{Cr}{Chromium}};
        \node[name=Mo, below of=Cr, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{42}{95.94}{Mo}{Molybdenum}};
        \node[name=W, below of=Mo, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{74}{183.84}{W}{Tungsten}};
        \node[name=Sg, below of=W, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{106}{266}{Sg}{Seaborgium}};
        
        %% Group 7 - VIIB
        \node[name=Mn, right of=Cr, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{25}{54.938}{Mn}{Manganese}};
        \node[name=Tc, below of=Mn, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{43}{96}{Tc}{Technetium}};
        \node[name=Re, below of=Tc, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{75}{186.21}{Re}{Rhenium}};
        \node[name=Bh, below of=Re, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{107}{264}{Bh}{Bohrium}};
        
        %% Group 8 - VIIIB
        \node[name=Fe, right of=Mn, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{26}{55.845}{Fe}{Iron}};
        \node[name=Ru, below of=Fe, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{44}{101.07}{Ru}{Ruthenium}};
        \node[name=Os, below of=Ru, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{76}{190.23}{Os}{Osmium}};
        \node[name=Hs, below of=Os, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{108}{277}{Hs}{Hassium}};
        
        %% Group 9 - VIIIB
        \node[name=Co, right of=Fe, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{27}{58.933}{Co}{Cobalt}};
        \node[name=Rh, below of=Co, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{45}{102.91}{Rh}{Rhodium}};
        \node[name=Ir, below of=Rh, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{77}{192.22}{Ir}{Iridium}};
        \node[name=Mt, below of=Ir, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{109}{268}{Mt}{Meitnerium}};
        
        %% Group 10 - VIIIB
        \node[name=Ni, right of=Co, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{28}{58.693}{Ni}{Nickel}};
        \node[name=Pd, below of=Ni, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{46}{106.42}{Pd}{Palladium}};
        \node[name=Pt, below of=Pd, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{78}{195.08}{Pt}{Platinum}};
        \node[name=Ds, below of=Pt, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{110}{281}{Ds}{Darmstadtium}};
        
        %% Group 11 - IB
        \node[name=Cu, right of=Ni, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{29}{63.546}{Cu}{Copper}};
        \node[name=Ag, below of=Cu, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{47}{107.87}{Ag}{Silver}};
        \node[name=Au, below of=Ag, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{79}{196.97}{Au}{Gold}};
        \node[name=Rg, below of=Au, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{111}{280}{Rg}{Roentgenium}};
        
        %% Group 12 - IIB
        \node[name=Zn, right of=Cu, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{30}{65.39}{Zn}{Zinc}};
        \node[name=Cd, below of=Zn, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{48}{112.41}{Cd}{Cadmium}};
        \node[name=Hg, below of=Cd, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{80}{200.59}{Hg}{Mercury}};
        \node[name=Uub, below of=Hg, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{112}{285}{Uub}{Ununbium}};
        
        %% Group 13 - IIIA
        \node[name=Ga, right of=Zn, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{31}{69.723}{Ga}{Gallium}};
        \node[name=Al, above of=Ga, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{13}{26.982}{Al}{Aluminium}};
        \node[name=B, above of=Al, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{5}{10.811}{B}{Boron}};
        \node[name=In, below of=Ga, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{49}{114.82}{In}{Indium}};
        \node[name=Tl, below of=In, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{81}{204.38}{Tl}{Thallium}};
        \node[name=Uut, below of=Tl, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{113}{284}{Uut}{Ununtrium}};
        
        %% Group 14 - IVA
        \node[name=C, right of=B, Nonmetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{6}{12.011}{C}{Carbon}};
        \node[name=Si, below of=C, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{14}{28.086}{Si}{Silicon}};
        \node[name=Ge, below of=Si, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{32}{72.64}{Ge}{Germanium}};
        \node[name=Sn, below of=Ge, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{50}{118.71}{Sn}{Tin}};
        \node[name=Pb, below of=Sn, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{82}{207.2}{Pb}{Lead}};
        \node[name=Uuq, below of=Pb, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{114}{289}{Uuq}{Ununquadium}};
        
        %% Group 15 - VA
        \node[name=N, right of=C, Nonmetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{7}{14.007}{N}{Nitrogen}};
        \node[name=P, below of=N, Nonmetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{15}{30.974}{P}{Phosphorus}};
        \node[name=As, below of=P, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{33}{74.922}{As}{Arsenic}};
        \node[name=Sb, below of=As, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{51}{121.76}{Sb}{Antimony}};
        \node[name=Bi, below of=Sb, Metal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{83}{208.98}{Bi}{Bismuth}};
        \node[name=Uup, below of=Bi, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{115}{288}{Uup}{Ununpentium}};
        
        %% Group 16 - VIA
        \node[name=O, right of=N, Nonmetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{8}{15.999}{O}{Oxygen}};
        \node[name=S, below of=O, Nonmetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{16}{32.065}{S}{Sulphur}};
        \node[name=Se, below of=S, Nonmetal] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{34}{78.96}{Se}{Selenium}};
        \node[name=Te, below of=Se, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{52}{127.6}{Te}{Tellurium}};
        \node[name=Po, below of=Te, Metalloid] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{84}{209}{Po}{Polonium}};
        \node[name=Uuh, below of=Po, Metal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{116}{293}{Uuh}{Ununhexium}};
        
        %% Group 17 - VIIA
        \node[name=F, right of=O, Halogen] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{9}{18.998}{F}{Flourine}};
        \node[name=Cl, below of=F, Halogen] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{17}{35.453}{Cl}{Chlorine}};
        \node[name=Br, below of=Cl, Halogen] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{35}{79.904}{Br}{Bromine}};
        \node[name=I, below of=Br, Halogen] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{53}{126.9}{I}{Iodine}};
        \node[name=At, below of=I, Halogen] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{85}{210}{At}{Astatine}};
        \node[name=Uus, below of=At, Element] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{117}{292}{Uus}{Ununseptium}}; 
        
        %% Group 18 - VIIIA
        \node[name=Ne, right of=F, NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{10}{20.180}{Ne}{Neon}};
        \node[name=He, above of=Ne, NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{2}{4.0025}{He}{Helium}};
        \node[name=Ar, below of=Ne, NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{18}{39.948}{Ar}{Argon}};
        \node[name=Kr, below of=Ar, NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{36}{83.8}{Kr}{Krypton}};
        \node[name=Xe, below of=Kr, NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{54}{131.29}{Xe}{Xenon}};
        \node[name=Rn, below of=Xe, NobleGas] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{86}{222}{Rn}{Radon}};
        \node[name=Uuo, below of=Rn, Nonmetal] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{118}{294}{Uuo}{Ununoctium}}; 
        
        %% Period
        \node[name=Period1, left of=H, PeriodLabel] {1};
        \node[name=Period2, left of=Li, PeriodLabel] {2};
        \node[name=Period3, left of=Na, PeriodLabel] {3}; 
        \node[name=Period4, left of=K, PeriodLabel] {4}; 
        \node[name=Period5, left of=Rb, PeriodLabel] {5};
        \node[name=Period6, left of=Cs, PeriodLabel] {6};
        \node[name=Period7, left of=Fr, PeriodLabel] {7};
        
        %% Group
        \node[name=Group1, above of=H, GroupLabel] {1 \hfill IA};
        \node[name=Group2, above of=Be, GroupLabel] {2 \hfill IIA};
        \node[name=Group3, above of=Sc, GroupLabel] {3 \hfill IIIA};
        \node[name=Group4, above of=Ti, GroupLabel] {4 \hfill IVB};
        \node[name=Group5, above of=V, GroupLabel] {5 \hfill VB};
        \node[name=Group6, above of=Cr, GroupLabel] {6 \hfill VIB};
        \node[name=Group7, above of=Mn, GroupLabel] {7 \hfill VIIB};
        \node[name=Group8, above of=Fe, GroupLabel] {8 \hfill VIIIB};
        \node[name=Group9, above of=Co, GroupLabel] {9 \hfill VIIIB};
        \node[name=Group10, above of=Ni, GroupLabel] {10 \hfill VIIIB};
        \node[name=Group11, above of=Cu, GroupLabel] {11 \hfill IB};
        \node[name=Group12, above of=Zn, GroupLabel] {12 \hfill IIB};
        \node[name=Group13, above of=B, GroupLabel] {13 \hfill IIIA};
        \node[name=Group14, above of=C, GroupLabel] {14 \hfill IVA};
        \node[name=Group15, above of=N, GroupLabel] {15 \hfill VA};
        \node[name=Group16, above of=O, GroupLabel] {16 \hfill VIA};
        \node[name=Group17, above of=F, GroupLabel] {17 \hfill VIIA};
        \node[name=Group18, above of=He, GroupLabel] {18 \hfill VIIIA};
        
        %% Lanthanide
        \node[name=La, below of=Rf, LanthanideActinide, yshift=-1cm] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{57}{138.91}{La}{Lanthanum}};
        \node[name=Ce, right of=La, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{58}{140.12}{Ce}{Cerium}};
        \node[name=Pr, right of=Ce, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{59}{140.91}{Pr}{Praseodymium}};
        \node[name=Nd, right of=Pr, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{60}{144.24}{Nd}{Neodymium}};
        \node[name=Pm, right of=Nd, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{61}{145}{Pm}{Promethium}};
        \node[name=Sm, right of=Pm, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{62}{150.36}{Sm}{Samarium}};
        \node[name=Eu, right of=Sm, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{63}{151.96}{Eu}{Europium}};
        \node[name=Gd, right of=Eu, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{64}{157.25}{Gd}{Gadolinium}};
        \node[name=Tb, right of=Gd, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{65}{158.93}{Tb}{Terbium}};
        \node[name=Dy, right of=Tb, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{66}{162.50}{Dy}{Dysprosium}};
        \node[name=Ho, right of=Dy, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{67}{164.93}{Ho}{Holmium}};
        \node[name=Er, right of=Ho, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{68}{167.26}{Er}{Erbium}};
        \node[name=Tm, right of=Er, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{69}{168.93}{Tm}{Thulium}};
        \node[name=Yb, right of=Tm, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{70}{173.04}{Yb}{Ytterbium}};
        \node[name=Lu, right of=Yb, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{71}{174.97}{Lu}{Lutetium}};
        
        %% Actinide
        \node[name=Ac, below of=La, LanthanideActinide, yshift=-1cm] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{89}{227}{Ac}{Actinium}};
        \node[name=Th, right of=Ac, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{90}{232.04}{Th}{Thorium}};
        \node[name=Pa, right of=Th, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{91}{231.04}{Pa}{Protactinium}};
        \node[name=U, right of=Pa, LanthanideActinide] {\NaturalElementTextFormat{92}{238.03}{U}{Uranium}};
        \node[name=Np, right of=U, LanthanideActinide] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{93}{237}{Np}{Neptunium}};
        \node[name=Pu, right of=Np, LanthanideActinide] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{94}{244}{Pu}{Plutonium}};
        \node[name=Am, right of=Pu, LanthanideActinide] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{95}{243}{Am}{Americium}};
        \node[name=Cm, right of=Am, LanthanideActinide] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{96}{247}{Cm}{Curium}};
        \node[name=Bk, right of=Cm, LanthanideActinide] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{97}{247}{Bk}{Berkelium}};
        \node[name=Cf, right of=Bk, LanthanideActinide] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{98}{251}{Cf}{Californium}};
        \node[name=Es, right of=Cf, LanthanideActinide] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{99}{252}{Es}{Einsteinium}};
        \node[name=Fm, right of=Es, LanthanideActinide] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{100}{257}{Fm}{Fermium}};
        \node[name=Md, right of=Fm, LanthanideActinide] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{101}{258}{Md}{Mendelevium}};
        \node[name=No, right of=Md, LanthanideActinide] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{102}{259}{No}{Nobelium}};
        \node[name=Lr, right of=No, LanthanideActinide] {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{103}{262}{Lr}{Lawrencium}};
        
        %% Draw dotted lines connecting Lanthanide breakout to main table
        \draw (LaLu.north west) edge[dotted] (La.north west)
        (LaLu.north east) edge[dotted] (Lu.north east)
        (LaLu.south west) edge[dotted] (La.south west)
        (LaLu.south east) edge[dotted] (Lu.south east);
        %% Draw dotted lines connecting Actinide breakout to main table
        \draw (AcLr.north west) edge[dotted] (Ac.north west)
        (AcLr.north east) edge[dotted] (Lr.north east)
        (AcLr.south west) edge[dotted] (Ac.south west)
        (AcLr.south east) edge[dotted] (Lr.south east);
        
        %% Legend
        \draw[black, AlkaliMetalFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-0.0em)$)
        rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Alkali Metal};
        \draw[black, AlkalineEarthMetalFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-1.5em)$)
        rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Alkaline Earth Metal};
        \draw[black, MetalFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-3.0em)$)
        rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Metal};
        \draw[black, MetalloidFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-4.5em)$)
        rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Metalloid};
        \draw[black, NonmetalFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-6.0em)$)
        rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Non-metal};
        \draw[black, HalogenFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-7.5em)$)
        rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Halogen};
        \draw[black, NobleGasFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-9.0em)$)
        rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Noble Gas};
        \draw[black, LanthanideActinideFill] ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (1em,-10.5em)$)
        rectangle +(1em, 1em) node[right, yshift=-1ex]{Lanthanide/Actinide};
        
        \node at ($(La.north -| Fr.west) + (5em,-15em)$) [name=elementLegend, Element, fill=white]
        {\NaturalElementTextFormat{Z}{mass}{Symbol}{Name}};
        \node[Element, fill=white, right of=elementLegend, xshift=1em]
        {\SyntheticElementTextFormat{}{}{man-made}{}} ;
        
        %% Diagram Title
        \node at (H.west -| Fe.north) [name=diagramTitle, TitleLabel]
        {(Mendeleev's) Periodic Table of Chemical Elements via Ti\emph{k}Z};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    asdf
\end{document}
```

Comment: I haven’t tested to see if that’s the real or the only problem, but inserting complex, conditional `\pdfliteral` commands into a PDF that turns out to be corrupted makes me very suspicious.

Comment: I think the workarounds to fake outline fonts might be too clever by half. There’s been an old-fashioned METAFONT outline version of Computer Modern Sans Serif since 1992, which would give you pixelated bitmaps if you tried to use it in a PDF, but code written today might use `cmathbb`.